# Add Google Hangout to a website programmatically

Tags: join, web, gmail, google-hangouts

I'm trying to add Google hangout to my website programmatically, so that whenever a user clicks on start a new Google hangout, it will create a new one and other people from my website will be able to join it. Can this be done?

Also, can people create or join a hangout if you don't have a Gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to do exactly the same thing too, i found this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4 , i coded every steps but at the end there is a crash, the app is not downloaded by the Hangout service. Try it to and lets me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will let you know